# [Rails+grape]jbuilderで関連づけしたテーブルの情報をAPIでjson形式で出力する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, grape

jbuilderでjsonのテンプレの作り方で悩んでいます。

Userと関連づけしたPostの情報をjsonで出すためにはどのようにjsonのテンプレートを書けばいいでしょうか。

理想として
GET ~/api/v1/users/allで

id
user_name
user_account
user_img
user.post.id
user.post.post_image

をjsonで出力したいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

## DB

```
User
id:integer
provider:string
user_name:string
user_account:
user_img:
has_many :posts    

Post
id: integer
user_id: integer
post_image: string
text: string
belongs_to :user
```

## api.rb

```
module Cospic
 class API < Grape::API
format :json 
formatter :json, Grape::Formatter::Jbuilder
   # APIアクセスに接頭辞を付加
   # ex) http://localhost:3000/api
   prefix "api"

   # APIアクセスにバージョン情報を付加
   # ex) http://localhost:3000/api/v1
   version 'v1', :using => :path

   resource "users" do
    # GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/all
     desc "ユーザー一覧"
      get :all, jbuilder:'users' do
       @users = User.all
      end
```

## app/view/api/user.jbuilder

```
json.articles @users do |user|
  json.(user, id, :user_name, :user_account, :user_img, :user.post.id, :user.post.post_image )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

記載方法はいろいろありますが、解りやすい次のように記載したら良いと思います。

```
# xxx.json.jbuilder
json.user_name    @user.user_name
json.user_account @user.user_account
json.user_img     @user.user_img

json.posts @user.posts.each do |post|
   json.post_id    post.id
   json.post_image post.post_image
end
```

jbuilderの簡単な使い方ですが、json.xxxのxxxの部分がJSONのキーになり、その引数がJSONのバリューになります。
階層構造にしたい場合は、json.posts @user.posts.eachのように記載すればよいです。

```
# 出力されるJSON
{ 
  "user_name"    => "user_name"
  "user_account" => "user_account",
  "user_img"     => "user_img",
  "posts" => [
    { "post_id" => 1 }, { "post_image" => "post_image" },
    { "post_id" => 1 }, { "post_image" => "post_image" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
また、追加で質問で失礼なのですが、
表示されたjsonが全て文字化けしており、
chromeのエンコードがShift_JISになってしまっています。

こちらはどのように変更すればよろしいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。